# Design pattern for creating an object with functional-like methods calls

Tags: design-patterns

A while ago I stumbled across a design pattern where an object is built by calling its methods in a compositional manner.

For example, to build a `Car`, one would do:

```py
car = Car().addWheels(
        [Wheel().addRim(material='alloy').addTyre(producer='pirelli') for i in range(4)]    
    ).addBrakes().setColor(color='red').build()
```

Is this a thing? If yes, what's the name of this approach/design pattern?

Comment: The general term is "method chaining". Otherwise, ["fluent interface"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) is a term that comes up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is one type of "Builder" pattern. Builders like these use "method chaining" (as mentioned by Heretic Monkey's comment) to gather values inside the "builder" instance. Once the user is done setting values, they call a final `build()` method that will typically verify consistency across the settings and possible infer others, then create the instance of whatever you wanted to build.

A more complex Builder pattern (outlined in the GoF Design Patterns book) includes a "director" component that orchestrates how the target instance is created. I like to compare this to a general contractor (the director) orchestrating how the specialist workers (plumbers, framers, electricians, etcetera) build a house. The collection of specialists comprise the "builder" in this version. Different directors can use the builder to create target instances.